# How to get same row data when click on button using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to fetch one row data from array using PHP. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if($bstatus==1) {
    $bikeArr=$data['data'];
    $count=1;
    foreach ($bikeArr as $v) {                                                                  
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $count++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['book_date']; ?>, <?php echo $v['book_time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['book_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['start_date']; ?>, <?php echo $v['start_time']; ?> /<br /> <?php echo $v['end_date']; ?>, <?php echo $v['end_time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['service_name']; ?> / <br /> <?php echo $v['model_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['booking_status_str']; ?></td>
         <td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#takemebookingsec">View Booking <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Here I need while user will click on `View Booking` button the exact same row index data will fetch from array and push into other variable.

Comment: you need javascript?

Comment: No i am doing using PHP.

Comment: yes, but to fecth and push variable, or reload page with params or ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the value of the primary key on the view booking button as in

```
<?php
echo $v['whatever_your_primary_key_is'];
?>
```

And then on the modal, get that id and do a query to get the current details You will need to parse these details as values of course on your html form in the modal view

To avoid using the database again, just echo the value of primary. But make sure you are still in the same loop to be able to get the current values. SO your modal must also be in the same loop

Try:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#takemebookingsec<?= $v['your_primary_key_goes_here']; ?>">View Booking <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
```

On your modal, still in the same loop,

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="takemebookingsec<?=$v['your_primary_key_goes_here']; ?>">
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $v['what_ever_name']; ?>">
    <!--Add other input here-->
 </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have all value inside array i dont want to go to db again.Can i do it using index value so that the respective value will be fetched.

Comment: How can i pass the primary_key here `<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#takemebookingsec">View Booking <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>`