# Detail button for one single row [PHP,MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

For the moment i have some php code that return a view of a div for each row with an image and some text inside but now i want that i can go to detail page from that row by clicking on a button but i doesn't know how to do that in php can somebody help me?

The code below is for the view of all the rows

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$dbname = "Motion";
$Teller = 0;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id, camera, filename, frame, file_type, time_stamp, event_time_stamp FROM security ".$WhereBetween."group by time_stamp";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     //echo "<table><tr><th>camera</th><th>filename</th><th>frame</th><th>file_type</th><th>time_stamp</th><th>event_time_stamp</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
     <div class='Blok'>
     <a href='#img".$teller."' class='Afbeelding'>
        <img src='".str_replace("/var/www/html","",$row["filename"])."' class='thumbnail'>
     </a>
     <div class='Tekst'>
       <h3>Motion Detection</h3>
       <p>
         Camera ID: ".$row["camera"]."<br>
         Timestamp: ".$row["time_stamp"]."<br>
         Filename:".str_replace("/var/www/html/img/","",$row["filename"])."
       </p>
     //Here i want the button to go to detail page
     </div>
     </div>";
```

Comment: what value you have for `WhereBetween` and there is not space before `"group by"`

Comment: the whereBetween is just for a datetimepicker so whenn somebody chose a range for the time_stamp from then to then and when there is no range set he show all the results and the group by is that here is only one row par second

Comment: Also there should be space before `group` like this `" group by time_stamp"` otherwise your date and group will concatenate

Comment: The space is in the where between so that is not a problem :p

Answer (score 0):

I would write this answer but I am busy.  I answered a similar question. Check this [How to get same row data when click on button using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342194/how-to-get-same-row-data-when-click-on-button-using-php/42342254#42342254)

So what you do is quite simple.  In your while loop,  put the value of your primary key on your modal onclick. 
That would link to your bootstrap View modal

Please comment if it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Please specify $WhereBetween in below code.

```
$servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "1234";
        $dbname = "Motion";
        $Teller = 0;
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $sql = "SELECT id, camera, filename, frame, file_type, time_stamp, event_time_stamp FROM security ".$WhereBetween."group by time_stamp";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
             //echo "<table><tr><th>camera</th><th>filename</th><th>frame</th><th>file_type</th><th>time_stamp</th><th>event_time_stamp</th></tr>";
             // output data of each row
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               echo "<!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
             <div class='Blok'>
             <a href='#img".$teller."' class='Afbeelding'>
                <img src='".str_replace("/var/www/html","",$row["filename"])."' class='thumbnail'>
             </a>
             <div class='Tekst'>
               <h3>Motion Detection</h3>
               <p>
                 Camera ID: ".$row["camera"]."<br>
                 Timestamp: ".$row["time_stamp"]."<br>
                 Filename:".str_replace("/var/www/html/img/","",$row["filename"])."
               </p>
             //Here i want the button to go to detail page
              <button onclick=\"window.location='http://example.com/index?id=".$row["ID"]."'\">Kill</button>
             </div>
             </div>";
          }
    }
```